# Как с помощью ngresource работать с удалённым сервером

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, angularjs

Есть сайт, написанный на на angular, с использованием rest api, api отдаёт json, ngresource забирает, всё хорошо, пока это всё действо происходит  на одном сервере.

Ngresource работает по ajax,  следовательно, при попытке получить или заслать данные на другой сервер, будет ошибка в правах. Можно использовать jsonP, но тогда как бы придётся переписать

```
 var resource = $resource(url,
                {callback: "JSON_CALLBACK"},
                {
                    get: {method: "JSONP"}
                }
            );
```

Tеряется весь смысл rest api, там как бы используются заголовки post, get, delete, put.

А вопрос появился, когда попробовал собрать в cordova + ionic мобильное приложение.

Можно, конечно, на сервере вырубить  Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
```

Если кто-то знает правильный выход, подскажите.

Comment: вообще мобильному приложению должно было быть все равно на _Access-Control-Allow-Origin_

Comment: @Grundy при отладке оно запускается в браузер, и при компиляции я так понимаю получается какая то упрощённая версия браузера

Comment: при компиляции должно было получаться нативное приложение, а при отладке в браузере какой урл пишется?

Comment: @Grundy ionic serve http://localhost:8100/

Comment: ага, ну по крайней мере для отладки можно прописать что-то вроде `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: localhost:8100'` А уже собранное приложение пробовали запускать?

Comment: @Grundy нет ещё не пробовал, запускать, компилил до подключения angular, попробую сделать как вы сказали, может поможет

Comment: @Grundy скомпиленное приложение нормально коннектится, настроил просто мок ответы для тестирования

Comment: `@SergeEsmanovich ок

Answer (score 1):

Мне в отладке ионик приложений очень помог плагин для хрома: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Comment: Попробую использовать